# Unable to mark files in directory listing from `C-x C-d`

Tags: key-bindings, help

I was just wondering if anyone has noticed the following behaviour after doing `C-x C-d`.

I use `C-x C-d` to navigate to a directories and subdirectories with pdfs. Then I try to mark a pdf file with `M-x dired-mark`, but I get the following message `No subdir-alist in *Directory*`.
Does anyone know what is going on here? Why do I get this message? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-d</kbd> doesn't run `dired` but `list-directory`. To invoke `dired`, use <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>.

Comment: Oh crap. How I didn't see that. BTW any suggestions when renaming files using regex to replace spaces and hyphens with underscores. Is this regex valid `'s/ /_/g' *` when replacing spaces? Thanks!

Comment: Please considering posting your comment question as a question, if you want an answer. Thx.